# Function fails to fully build JSON under load

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I'm working on an OSS project called [pSConfig Web Admin (PWA)](https://github.com/perfsonar/psconfig-web). The biggest problem we're having is that under load, the generated JSON will occasionally be delivered incomplete (as documented in [this issue](https://github.com/perfsonar/psconfig-web/issues/214)).

When it fails, it seems to always fail in the same way. Namely, the *groups* object only includes one item when it should contain more. For example, instead of getting this:

```
{
  "archives": { … },
  "addresses": { … },
  "groups": {
    "Group 1": { … },
    "Group 2": { … },
    "Group 3": { … },
    "Group 4": { … }
  },
  "tests": { … },
  "schedules": { … },
  "tasks": { … },
  "_meta": { … },
  "hosts": { … }
}
```

We'll get this:

```
{
  "archives": { … },
  "addresses": { … },
  "groups": {
    "Group 4": { … }
  },
  "tests": { … },
  "schedules": { … },
  "tasks": { … },
  "_meta": { … },
  "hosts": { … }
}
```

I think the problem is that some async calls are returning before they really should and I fear [Zalgo has been unleashed](https://blog.izs.me/2013/08/designing-apis-for-asynchrony/) since it doesn't happen all the time. I suspect the problem is in the [exports._process_published_config function](https://github.com/perfsonar/psconfig-web/blob/35e7db9033efba40938b1d38990a787643ccd9a1/api/pub/meshconfig.js#L548). Namely how it uses [async.parallel](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#parallel) inside [async.eachSeries](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#eachSeries) (but this is just speculation on my part):

```
exports._process_published_config = function (_config, opts, cb) {
    …

    async.eachSeries(
        _config.tests,
        function (test, next_test) {
            var type = test.mesh_type;

            if (!test.enabled) return next_test();
            async.parallel(
                [
                    function (next) {
                        //a group
                        if (!test.agroup) return next();
                        generate_group_members(
                            test,
                            test.agroup,
                            test_service_types,
                            type,
                            next,
                            "a-"
                        );
                    },
                    function (next) {
                        //b group
                        if (!test.bgroup) return next();
                        generate_group_members(
                            test,
                            test.bgroup,
                            test_service_types,
                            type,
                            next,
                            "b-"
                        );
                    },
                    function (next) {
                        if (!test.nahosts) return next();
                        resolve_hosts(test.nahosts, function (err, hosts) {
                            if (err) return next(err);
                            test.nahosts = hosts;
                            hosts.forEach(function (host) {
                                host_catalog[host._id] = host;
                            });
                            next();
                        });
                    },
                    function (next) {
                        //testspec
                        if (!test.testspec) return next();

                        resolve_testspec(test.testspec, function (err, row) {
                            if (err) return next(err);
                            test.testspec = row;

                            //suppress testspecs that does't meet min host version
                            if (!_config._host_version) return next();
                            var hostv = parseInt(_config._host_version[0]);
                            var minver =
                                config.meshconfig.minver[test.service_type];
                            for (var k in test.testspec.specs) {
                                //if minver is set for this testspec, make sure host version meets it
                                if (minver && k in minver) {
                                    if (hostv < minver[k])
                                        delete test.testspec.specs[k];
                                }
                            }
                            next();
                        });
                    },
                ],
                next_test
            );
        },
        function (err) {
            …
        }
    );
};
```

Has anyone seen something like this before or see anything in this code that stands out as completely wrong?

I'm trying to get out of *callback hell* by rewriting portions of this using promises and async/await, but I'm not entirely sure that'll solve this problem. In any case it's very difficult to rewrite due to how the callbacks are so deeply nested.

Comment: On Errors you do simple `return next(err)` are you logging this errors anywhere to (you also use `return next()` where there is nothing returned by some functions - you should also check if there is nothing or there is error there - maybe that is why you are getting not full data ((like, on load, some things timeouts and you then ignore them instead of retrying or returning error))

Comment: It also might be that due to how the `async.parallel` works, some things are returned properly, then one does errors, and all others are then stopped - as this `paralell` stops execution after error occures?

Answer (score 0):

very likely that `generate_group_members` at first checks whether 'groups' array is empty or not, then does some async invocation and then initalizes 'groups' as [] and pushes there something. So two parallel invocations of generate_group_members can find 'groups' empty and after that initialize that as [].